# What is difference between mongodump and mongoexport?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I know that when we have to take full backup at database & collection level we use mongodump but with mongodump we can take backup of a particular record also so what is difference between mongodump and mongoexport?

Comment: Which respect wyou want to do the difference between mongodump & mongoexport? Could you elaborate bit more.

Comment: Hi Haidar, My question is simple if mongodump can take backup of records (Partial backup) then why we use mongoexport for taking backup of records. if there is any importance of mongoexport then what is that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`mongodump` generates binary copies of data; it creates better, more efficient backups.

`mongoexport` can create JSON files; these can be used by other programs, and are basically human-readable as is.

Comment: What does your answer add to https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/194373/6219?

Answer (score 6):

As per MongoDB BOL [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)
mongodump is a utility for creating a binary export of the contents of a database. `mongodump` can export data from either `mongod` or `mongos` instances.
`mongodump` only captures the documents in the database.The resulting backup is space efficient.
By default, `mongodump` does not capture the contents of the `local database`.

Changed in `version 3.4`: **MongoDB 3.4** added support for read-only views. By default, `mongodump` only captures a `view’s metadata`: it does not create a binary export of the documents included in the view. To capture the documents in a view use `--viewsAsCollections`.

Where as MongoDB document [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) mongoexport is a utility that produces a **JSON** or **CSV** export of data stored in a MongoDB instance.
Run mongoexport from the system command line, not the `mongo` shell.

**mongoexport Required Access**

1. `mongoexport` requires **read access** on the target database.
2. Ensure that the connecting user possesses, at a minimum, the read
   role on the target database.
3. When connecting to a `mongod` or `mongos` that enforces Authentication,
   ensure you use the required security parameters based on the
   `configured authentication mechanism`.

Also, do note [that](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongoexport/#type-fidelity):

> **Warning:** Avoid using **mongoimport** and **mongoexport** for full instance production backups. They do not reliably preserve all rich BSON data
> types, because JSON can only represent a subset of the types supported
> by BSON. Use **mongodump** and **mongorestore** as in [MongoDB Backup Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/)
> for this kind of functionality.

Although, no such warning exists in the [MongoDB 4.4 documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoexport/).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.web-technology-experts-notes.in/2016/09/what-is-difference-between-mongoexport-and-mongodump.html)

mongodump is a utility for creating a binary export of the contents of a database. mongodump is used for full backup, partial backup, syncing from production to staging/development, and changing the storage engine.